# Database indexing: Example

Tags: database, indexing, tuples, relation

I have an exam soon and I want to know how to solve these questions about indexing:

1.A database consist of a relation R(A,B,C). A and B are integers [0,10 000] (4B each) and C is a varchar(20) (20B). The relation R consist of 10^6 tuples. The blocksize is 2048 B.

A)  How many blocks do we have to read (best and worst) if we ask this query if we have an B+-tree index on B:

SELECT C FROM R WHERE A=100 and B=10

B) Does it make sense to index A? If yes, what type of indeces are the best?

**Another similar question is:**

2.A database consist of a relation R(A,B,C). A and B are integers [0,10 000] and C is a varchar(150). The relation R consist of 10^6 tuples. The blocksize is 2048 B and A, B are the keys.

A) How many blocks do we have to read in best and worst case if we ask the query " SELECT C FROM R WHERE A=4711 and:

- We don't have an index.
- We have a B+-tree index on A and B.

b) Does it make sense to index B separetely and A separetely instead of having one index on A and B. What type of indeces are the best?

**EDIT**:

Here is what I have done:

**Question 1**
*A)*

A tuple is of size = 20+4+4=28 B

2048/28=73 tuples/block rounded down

10^6/73= 13 699 blocks for the whole relation, rounded up

*Indexreadings*: 
4*n+4(n+1)<=2048 B    => n=255 rounded down

first level of the B+tree= 255<10^6 
No

second level of the B+tree= 255*256<10^6
 No

third level of the B+tree= 255*256*257>10^6
Yes the 10^6 tuples can fit in a B+tree with height 3.

*Datareadings*:
If we assume that the A=100 has the probability 1/10001  and B=10 has the same probability then we have:

1/10001*1/10001*10^6 rounded up = 1 tuples

In worst and best case: 1 tuples= 1 block

Then we have 3+1 blockreadings

Is it right?

I don't know how to do the B)..

And I really don't know how to answer Question 2 .. Please help me

Comment: If you show your work up to the point where you get stuck you will likely get a reply sooner.  Just dumping a homework problem on SO is considered to be outside the site's posting guidelines.

Comment: Done. I hope you people will help me now.

Answer (score 0):

Just some notes. Your 1A best case seems almost right(Kinda, but se added: at the bottom), but I think your block size calculation is wrong. Only (The value of) B and a pointer/reference to the needed disk block should be stored in the b+ index tree. Neither A nor C should be in the b+ tree at all.

And your worst case is really wrong. There is no requirement that B is unique, and there is no need to do probability when talking about worst case.

So imagine what happens if B=10 in all your tuples. Then you will have to read them all to find the values where A=100. (Remember you are asked for best/worst case not average).

This worst case example is also your hint to solve question 1B. An index might be useful if you have so many values with equal B values that they can't be located in a few blocks. (You can do the exact math).

2A don't seem so difficult. If we don't have an index then you need to read 1 block in the best case, and all the blocks in the worst case. (This assume that A is unique. This is what A being a key means right?)

But I am a bit confused about this last question. If A and B are 2 different (foreign???) keys, then having a combined index on them both seems wrong.

ps: It is a few years ago I did this for university, so I may be wrong, but I hope I at least gave you something to think about :}

Added: -----------------

My note about your calculations of how many entries you can have in a single node seems really off.  Try this instead: (Still from memory, so sorry for any errors).

An entry in your b+ tree, contains 2 values of B (min/max) and a disk block reference for the block containing the values between min and max. So each entry is 12 bytes (Assuming 4 byte block references) and you can thus store 2048/12=170 entries in each block.